# Django mysql (mariadb Server version: 5.5.68) database not working with wsgi.py

Tags: django, mysql-connector

I have a working django application that works fine in the development server. As soon as I try to use it as a production server application using Apache and wsgi.py it gives me errors.

With MYSQL I get the following errors:

```
[Fri Sep 03 13:27:22.424881 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 15424] [remote 172.30.0.54:49967]     import MySQLdb as Database
[Fri Sep 03 13:27:22.424920 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 15424] [remote 172.30.0.54:49967]   File "/home/bakert/.local/share/virtualenvs/trackx_proj_master-nygxcPTP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
[Fri Sep 03 13:27:22.424952 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 15424] [remote 172.30.0.54:49967]     version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
[Fri Sep 03 13:27:22.424982 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 15424] [remote 172.30.0.54:49967] NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

When I do a pip freeze - My requirements file looks like this:

```
asgiref==3.3.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
dj-email-url==1.0.2
Django==3.1.12
django-cache-url==3.2.3
django-crispy-forms==1.9.2
django-ranged-response==0.2.0
django-simple-captcha==0.5.14
environs==8.0.0
marshmallow==3.12.1
mod-wsgi-httpd==2.4.48.1
mysqlclient==2.0.1
pathlib==1.0.1
Pillow==8.1.0
python-dotenv==0.17.1
pytz==2021.1
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
```

So - it seems like the virtual environment should know about mysql - but it doesn't seem to find it.  I tried reverting back to sqlite - just to try it - and it complained about sqlite version... so it seems something's not right in the virtual environment that wsgi.py is trying to use.

My wsgi.py looks like this:

```
    import os,sys

    sys.path.append('/var/www/trackx_proj/trackx_root')
    sys.path.append('/usr/lib64/mysql')
    sys.path.append('/home/bakert/.local/share/virtualenvs/trackx_proj_master-   
        nygxcPTP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb')

    sys.path.append('/home/bakert/.local/share/virtualenvs/trackx_proj_master-
        nygxcPTP/lib/python3.9/site-packages')

    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'trackx.settings')

    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Anyone know what gives here?

Thanks

Comment: Get rid of that sys.path line that references `MySQLdb`. In general, all modification of `sys.path` is an antipattern!

Comment: I could certainly remove it (It wasn't there at first - so obviously it's not helping at all). Just wonder why it cant find MySQL while development server can..

Comment: If you're using mod_wsgi with Python, you should use it to set up the virtualenv and working directory, not sys.path management.

Comment: Not following you, when you say I should use it to set up the virtualenv and working directory, then where DO I set the MysqDB directory?

Comment: You should have your dependencies installed into your virtualenv, then have mod_wsgi deal with using the correct virtualenv and pythonpath; your wsgi.py should never need to touch sys.path.